# CKEDITOR how to Identify scroll event

Tags: ckeditor

Does anyone know how to catch the 'scroll' event in CKEDITOR? there is easy to identify change and other events, but I am unable to cathc Scroll event..

`CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() {alert('text changed!');});`

but when want to use same for scroll it does not working

`CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('scroll', function() {alert('I am scrolling!');});`

does anyone know some workaround?

Thx a lot
M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to know is that [CKEditor's instance](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor) (which you get from `CKEDITOR.instances` object) is not a DOM element. It indeed fires some events like [`change`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change), [`focus`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-focus), [`blur`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-blur), or [`save`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-save), but they are just short cuts or facades to more complex things.

Therefore, if you want to add a DOM event listener, then you need to retrieve the "editable" element (an element in which editing happens). It can be accessed by the [`editor.editable()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-editable) method. However, the tricky thing about editable element is that it's not always available, it's not ready right after starting editor initialization and that editor may replace this element with a new one (usually after switching between modes). Therefore, editor fires a [`contentDom`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom) to notify that the new editable is available and the editable has an [`attachListener`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-attachListener) method which, unlike the [`on`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-on) cleans the listener when editable is destroyed.

The way to use all those methods is explained in the documentation and there are code samples, but just to save you one click:

```
editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    var editable = editor.editable();

    editable.attachListener( editable.getDocument(), 'scroll', function() {
        console.log( 'Editable has been scrolled' );
    });
});
```

**Update:** I forgot that for 'scroll' event you have to listen on document. I updated the code above.

Comment: First I thing thare was something wrong but look I have some problem in code, however this is not working either.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I updated my answer and here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/9mVsm/3/